# cake email internal error

Tags: email, cakephp

So I am debugging some code that someone else wrote and it utilises the cakephp cake email thing. I have never used it before and have never written an email function before either.

When the function executes it outputs cakes standard: "Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred"
as well as this line:

SMTP Error: 535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 h66sm5396348yhb.7 - gsmtp

The code is here:

```
    public function newAppEmail($email_addr, $password) {
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->config('default');

    $Email->sender(array('polarontest@gmail.com' => 'Polaron'));
    $Email->from(array('polarontest@gmail.com' => 'Polaron'));
    $Email->to($email_addr);
    $Email->subject('Eligibility Check');
    $Email->template('newapp');
    $Email->emailFormat('text');
    $Email->viewVars(array('name' => $this->request->data['Applicant']['first_name'], 'email' => $this->request->data['Applicant']['email'], 'password' => $password));
    $Email->attachments(array(
        'Polaron - PL Passport - Info Pack - 2013.pdf' => array(
            'file' => APP . 'documents/Email_attachments/Polaron - PL Passport - Info Pack - 2013.pdf',
            'mimetype' => 'pdf'),
    ));

    $Email->send();
}
```

and this is the config file:

```
<?php
```

class EmailConfig {

```
public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('email@email.com' => 'company name'),
    'sender' => array('email@email.com' => 'company name'),
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'email@email.com',
    'password' => 'password');

public $fast = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('email@email.com' => 'Test Mail name sender'),
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'email@email.com',
    'password' => 'password');
```

}

Can anyone shed some light on what might be wrong and where I should look to fix it?

Comment: You should check the logs under `/app/tmp/logs`

Comment: Use in $default 'timeout' => 30

Answer (score 0):

Well, SMTP Error 535 means that authentication fails, which is easy to find out.

The exception is thrown because of that. So get the right credentials and try again, this is not an issue of the php code but your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If your login / password is correct, test the configuration:

```
public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('email@gmail.com' => 'Name'),
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'email@gmail.com',
        'password' => '**********',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```